# How to solve 504 gateway timeout nginx

Tags: php, nginx, cron, http-status-code-504

I have run one cron file but it takes to much time and it's not run proper and gives me "504 gateway timeout nginx" error. How can I find a solution for this?

Comment: Dont run your cron jobs via HTTP calls, why you not using a proper cron job? XY problem?

Comment: i have use cron job using server

Comment: You can do that by making sure that in your php script you have `set_time_limit(0)` and increase `fastcgi_read_timeout` in your nginx config and then try

Comment: can you please tell me from where can i increse fastcgi_read_timeout ?